# How can I change the title bar of my IE when run Oracle Forms?

Tags: internet-explorer, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have almost 500 Oracle forms 10g.Users want to see the name of the forms in the IE title bar (uppermost portion seen in the screen when Internet Explorer is launched). Seemingly, one way is adding [webformsTitle in formsweb.cfg for all forms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a86202/chap05.htm) has explained the parameters in formsweb.cfg.

I wonder to know is there any way that I avoid doing it manually Can I change the default configuration so that I can see the windows title on my IE title bar as well, to avoid changing formsweb.cfg for all forms?

Comment: afaik webformsTitle in formsweb.cfg is for your *main* application - each form opens as a separate window *in* your application - so I doubt that's possible

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with 10g.

I've read with 11g you can call Javascript from the form, so you should be able to, but haven't actually done it.